# How i can set the Searchbar Inative and User click on this for open a Dialog

Tags: c#, android, searchview

My Question is how can i Build in Android C# an SreachView this is off by but Show and any User click on this a Dialog open and asked the User to give her ok.

I work in a Fragment

```
SearchView searchView;
searchView = (SearchView)View.FindViewById(Resource.Id.MenuSearchitem);
searchView.ClearFocus();
searchView.SetOnQueryTextListener(this);
searchView.SetOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(this);
searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);
searchView.SubmitButtonEnabled = true;
searchView.QueryHint = mapViewModel.AddressPlaceholder;
```

thats all fine, but nothing work for click on the searchbar and no dialog is open. 
follow ways i have used IOnFocusChangeListener and IOnSuggestionListener dont gave the right way for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use onTouchListner, wherever you will touch on the screen the touch event will be triggered, there you can check which widget is clicked just check it and open dialog in it.

Comment: i think my problem is by start the view. the searchview is completed on. but i need a serachview with disabled textfield. the user must click on the searchview an a dialog open for asked "you sure to search" or anythink ...

Comment: Ok what I have understand so far is that you should try something different instead of Searchview, you can try a linear layout with edittext inside linear layout put search icon before edit text under linear layout it will look like searchview and then put addTextWatcher on edittext, It might work for you. Thanks

Comment: hmm ok i will check , but i find the searchview very nice for work with this.

Comment: Can you please share the code and design so I can see what are you doing and what you wanna do.

Comment: Yes sure.  public void OnFocusChange(View v, bool hasFocus)
  {
   if (mapViewModel.IsSearchAllowed)
   {
    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Focus", ToastLength.Short).Show();
   }
   else
   {
    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Search off", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    searchView.Focusable = false;
   }
  }

Comment: oh man i found a dirty solution. in the OnFocusChange i use searchView.ClearFocus(); The Cursor is show a little moment and after this the Field is blocked. not the best solution but is works.